# Java Swing, scrollable HBox

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program where I'm trying to implement a scrollable HBox. Sadly the JSCrollPane doesn't seem to function at all and when the window gets too small the images just start to clip each other.

[image]

The pane with the images has the following code:

```
    public class Caller extends JPanel {

    public Caller() {
        initPanel();
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }

    public void addBall(Ball ball) {
        this.add(ball);
    }
}
```

And the main frame:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public GUI() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        initMainFrame();
        initCaller();
    }

    private void initCaller() {
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(caller, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        caller.addBall(new Ball(5));
        caller.addBall(new Ball(16));
        caller.addBall(new Ball(34));
        caller.addBall(new Ball(34));
        caller.addBall(new Ball(34));

        this.add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void initMainFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Main");
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500,200));
    }
}
```

Ball Draw Code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(ballImage, 0,0, this);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(designation, 20,ballImage.getHeight()/2);
}
```

Am I implementing the scroller in the wrong way?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Could you add the code for `Ball` ?

Comment: As pointed by @Berger, the problem seems to be in Ball class. I've tested your code replacing your Ball by a JPanel with a BorderLayout that includes a JLabel+ImageIcon and my images do not overlap.

Comment: @RubioRic Could be the issue, I'm actually using paint to draw the image... Updated main post with draw code.

Comment: Is your `Ball` class a `JComponent` ?

Comment: @Berger Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `Ball` `JComponent` is missing informations about its preferred/min/max sizes, so the `Caller` panel with the `BoxLayout` doesn't know what they are and when you reduce the width, your components will have their size reduced rather than the scrollpane reflecting the need for scrolling.

You will have to override the relevant methods of your `Ball` class e.g :

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

    return new Dimension(ballImage.width, ballImage.height);

}

@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {

    return new Dimension(ballImage.width, ballImage.height);

}

@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {

    return new Dimension(ballImage.width, ballImage.height);

}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!